# How to avoid duplication of task execution in celery? And how to assign an worker to an default queue

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord, celerybeat

My task executes more than once with two minutes. but scheduled for once in `celery_beat` queue.

Tried with restarting the celery with `supervisorctl` command as `supervisorctl stop all` and `supervisorctl stop all`

```js
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')

app.conf.task_default_queue = 'default'
app.conf.task_routes = {'cloudtemplates.tasks.get_metrics': {'queue': 'metrics'}}

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'load-softlyer-machine-images': {
        'task': 'load_ibm_machine_images',
        'schedule': crontab(0, 0, day_of_month='13'),
        'args': '',
        'options': {'queue': 'celery_beat'},
    }
}
```

Expected to run the sheduled task only once for on 13 th of every month.

Comment: I think [crontab](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.crontab) only receive keyword arguments try with `crontab(minute=0, hour=0, day_of_month='13')`

Comment: Also, try deleting your `celerybeat-schedule` wich is generated at the start of celery beat command, this depends on the way you start your `celery_beat`